# Hyperledger : get logged in user tcert attributes in chaincode

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I'm trying to develop a very simple example on Hyperledger Fabric blockchain with these steps : 
INIT: sets a Table containing a given asset "A" amount, referenced by an account number
INVOKE: for now, nothing
QUERY: prints the asset balance for a given account if you own the account or if you have a specific role that allows you to watch all accounts.

So, in my membersrvc.yaml, I added members, and attributes like this :

```
    eca:
        affiliations:
           banks_and_institutions:
              banks:
                  - bank_a
                  - bank_b
                  - bank_c
        users:
                # Users for usecase1
                client1: 1 client1 bank_a
                client2: 1 client2 bank_b
                client3: 1 client3 bank_c
                back_office: 1 back_office bank_c
                regulator: 1 regulator bank_c

    aca:
              # User attributes for usercase1
              attribute-entry-1: client1;bank_a;role;client;2015-01-01T00:00:00-03:00;;
              attribute-entry-2: client1;bank_a;account;client1;2015-01-01T00:00:00-03:00;;
              attribute-entry-3: client2;bank_b;role;client;2015-01-01T00:00:00-03:00;;
              attribute-entry-4: client2;bank_b;account;client2;2015-01-01T00:00:00-03:00;;
              attribute-entry-5: client3;bank_c;role;client;2015-01-01T00:00:00-03:00;;
              attribute-entry-6: client3;bank_c;account;client3;2015-01-01T00:00:00-03:00;;
              attribute-entry-7: back_office;bank_c;role;back_office;2015-01-01T00:00:00-03:00;;
              attribute-entry-8: back_office;bank_c;account;back_office;2015-01-01T00:00:00-03:00;;
              attribute-entry-9: regulator;bank_c;role;regulator;2015-01-01T00:00:00-03:00;;
              attribute-entry-10: regulator;bank_c;account;regulator;2015-01-01T00:00:00-03:00;;

          address: localhost:7054
          server-name: acap
          enabled: true
```

But my question is :

**How can I get and check these informations in my Query function of a chaincode ?**

What I mean by that is, with security enabled and command launch by a given user :

```
peer network login client1 -p client1

peer chaincode query -u client1 -n usecase1 -c '{"Function":"assets", "Args": ["some_username"]}'
```

Be able to get client1 role & account and apply my rule.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example for how to work with attributes can be found here:

```
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/examples/chaincode/go/asset_management_with_roles
```

In Query you can use shim method ReadCertAttribute:

```
callerRole, err := stub.ReadCertAttribute("role")
if err != nil {
   fmt.Printf("Error reading attribute 'role' [%v] \n", err)
   return nil, fmt.Errorf("Failed fetching caller role. Error was [%v]", err)
}
```

Keep in mind that attributes names should be clearly declared in  Deploy/Query/Invoke commands ("attributes": ["role", "account"]):

An example for Deploy:

```
curl -XPOST -d  '{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "deploy",  "params": {"type": 1,"chaincodeID": {"path": "github.com/PATH/TO/YOUR/CHAINCODE","language": "GOLANG"}, "ctorMsg": {"Function":"init",  "args": ["some_args"] },"secureContext": "client1", "attributes": ["role", "account"]},"id": 0}' http://localhost:7050/chaincode
```

An example for Query:

```
curl -XPOST -d  '{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "query", "params": {"type": 1, "chaincodeID": {"name": "!!CHAINCODE_ID!!"}, "ctorMsg": {"Function":"assets", "args": ["some_username"]}, "secureContext": "client1", "attributes": ["role", "account"]}, "id": 1}' http://localhost:7050/chaincode
```